# Simple open source ALU written in Verilog

Tags: verilog, 8051

I am working on a control unit as a project in my Verilog class. To get some burden off of me, I want to designed everything considering I have a 8051 type simple ALU already with me so I can work on the control unit only. But I am not really able to find verilog ALU code which is open source too. Where can one find this type of code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first place I would search for open source Verilog/VHDL code is [OpenCores](http://opencores.org).
They describe themselves as:

> the world’s largest site/community for development of hardware IP cores as open source

A quick search on the site led me to [this 8051 ALU module](http://opencores.org/websvn,filedetails?repname=8051&path=/8051/trunk/rtl/verilog/oc8051_alu.v).

Comment: Should be more than enough.

Comment: Yep OpenCore is great, some of their solutions have been implemented in commercial microcontrollers